# Bar code scanner in Android

Tags: android

I want to Create an application which can read the Ba Codes. I want to do this through my on application not using third party applications like 'ZXing'. Please any coding help or tatorial...

Comment: Tutorials are easily available online and can be found with a simple Google search. Post here when you have a more specific problem.

Comment: Why do you want to be responsible for the actual scanning code? If something changes hardware or software you will have more to manage for very little (if any) gain. You can integrate Zxing directly into your app, but it is heavily stated that this is not good practice.

Comment: From personal experience, don't integrate barcode scanning into your app. You'll never do it anywhere near as well as ZXing, so use their app. Use their IntentIntegrator class for the best experience.

Comment: @Raghav Sood can you suggest me any good Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I have already done an Android application by scanning directly a barcode with my app. I have used Zxing barcode sources to take functionnalities that I want and it's easy to make your own application which scans barcode.

More particularly, what you have to do is to design a screen which can take photos, then you just need to use the Camera object and when you have an image captured, put it in Bitmap format in parameter of one ZXing method. Then you will have the result and you can display it like you want.

If you have more specific questions about this, don't hesitate to ask. I can retrieve my code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent
and follow the explanation, in order to add the class and code described in the site.

Once you've implemented it the scanner added ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check out the free [Scandit barcode scanner SDK](http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/) for Android. It comes with a step-by-step guide, example code and instructional video how to get started and it also works with low-end Android devices that have no autofocus camera and/or limited resolution.

If you are interested in converting the UPC numbers scanned to product names, there is also a [product API](http://www.scandit.com/product-api/).

[Disclaimer: I am a developer at Scandit]